# How can I capture all images within <p> using regex?

Tags: html, regex

I've been struggling with this due to my lacking REGEX experience. I need to extract the pattern of all img tags in html which occur inside p tags. i.e:

```
<p>Hello <img src="bbc.co.uk" /> World</p>
<img src="google.com" />
<p>Crazy <img src="google.com"> Town</p>
```

Should return:

```
<img src="bbc.co.uk" />
<img src="google.com">
```

I have this regex so far which captures the img pattern:

```
<img .+?(?=>)>
```

However it captures all imgs, where as I need only those that appear within a p tags, but do NOT want the p tag to be included in the result.

Many thanks

Comment: You probably want to use a DOM parser rather than a regex.

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: Why are you using regex? jQuery selector might be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

If your programming language or tool supports capturing groups with regex, then you can use `<p[^>]*>[^<]*(?:<[^>]*>[^<]*)*?(<img[^>]*>)[^<]*(?:<[^>]*>[^<]*)*?</p>` to capture just the `img` tags within `p` tags.

Using Python as an example:

```
import re
html = '''<p>Hello <img src="bbc.co.uk" /> World</p>
<img src="stackoverflow.com" />
<p>Crazy <img src="google.com"> Town</p>'''
print(re.findall(r'<p[^>]*>[^<]*(?:<[^>]*>[^<]*)*?(<img[^>]*>)[^<]*(?:<[^>]*>[^<]*)*?</p>', html, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL))
```

This outputs:

```
['<img src="bbc.co.uk" />', '<img src="google.com">']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
    `<p>.*(<img[^>]*>).*<\/p>`

Use the inner group `()` for capture

Answer (score 0):

You can't. HTML is a context-free language and regular expressions can only denote regular languages.

Edit: You can probably one image tag but if you're expecting a dynamic amount of tags, you can't do it with one regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing html with a regex which is [not advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) you might use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

```js
let parser = new DOMParser();
let html = `<p>Hello <img src="bbc.co.uk" /> World</p>
<img src="google.com" />
<p>Crazy <img src="google.com"> Town</p>`;
let doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
let imgs = doc.querySelectorAll("p img");
imgs.forEach((img) => {
  console.log(img.outerHTML)
});
```